# exclude some pages from totalpage

Tags: page-numbering, lastpage

I use the `lastpage` package, and I would like to set a command as `\excludethispage` to put at pages I don't want to be counted in the total of page summoned by `\pageref{LastPage}` (for example, I would like to do it to pages of which I use the empty style of the package `fancyhdr`).

Comment: We need an example, especially to know how you are using the count. But see `pageslts` for ways to manage page numbering schemes which don't correspond to the underlying page number. If you just want to deduct a count from the total, though, just `\newcounter{excludedpages}` and put `\stepcounter{excludedpages}` on the empty ones. Then deduct that from the total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way with `\SuspendCounters` and `\ResumeSuspendedCounters` from my `xassoccnt` package, using the `total counter` feature which stores the value at the end of a compilation, making the value available in the next compilation.

Rather than manipulating the page counter itself (which is some strange fellow ;-)) I defined an associated counter for this (`totalpages`), which is suspended and resumed.

The `\dummypages` macro is just for filling up with dummy pages...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xassoccnt}

\NewTotalDocumentCounter{totalpages}
\DeclareAssociatedCounters{page}{totalpages}
\usepackage{blindtext}

% Just for doing the loop
\usepackage{forloop}
\newcounter{loopcntr}
\newcommand{\dummypages}[2][20]{%
  \forloop{loopcntr}{1}{\value{loopcntr} < \numexpr #1+1}{%
    #2\clearpage%
  }%
}


\begin{document}

There are \TotalValue{totalpages}\ pages in here!
\clearpage

\dummypages{\blindtext}

\SuspendCounters{totalpages} % Suspend the counting
\dummypages[10]{\textbf{Don't count on me!}}
\ResumeSuspendedCounters{totalpages} % Resume the counting of totalpages

\dummypages{\blindtext}



\end{document}
```